# Zxing scanner not working in debug mode Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, zxing

I am using Zxing library to scan a QR Code from my application. For some reason the scanner is working only if I install the app from apple testflight application. When I am deploying the app in the device using debug mode the scanner is not working. I am facing this issue in iOS.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.